# Nested foreach not giving correct results

Tags: linq, foreach

I have a program that is supposed to return a player's points accumulated over a number of engagements. Points are calculated basing on the number of people taking part in a particular engagement in relationship a player's ranking at that engagement.

I am currently running this code:

```
foreach (var player in players)
{
    singleCircuitPoints result = new singleCircuitPoints();
    result.player = player.play;
    result.team = player.team;

    var circuits = 
        (from r in unitOfWork.RegistrationRepository.Get(
                     includeProperties: "competition,player")
          where 
              r.competition.startDate.Year == competition.startDate.Year 
              && r.competition.beach == true 
              && r.competition.startDate <= competition.startDate 
              && r.corporate == corp 
              && r.player.pGender == gender 
              && r.partnerId == null
         select r.competition);

    int playerPoints = 0;
    int numPlayers = 0;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    foreach (Competition c in circuits)
    {
        if (player.play.registrations.Any(p => p.compId == c.compId))
        {
            var circuit = from a in allCircuits 
                          where a.compId == c.compId select a;

            numPlayers = circuit.Count();

            list = circuit.OrderBy(r => r.score.Sum())
                          .ThenBy(r => r.orderedStroke)
                          .Select(r => r.pId).ToList();

            for (int x = 0; x < list.Count(); x++)
            {
                int pos = list.IndexOf(player.play.pId);
                playerPoints = numPlayers - pos;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            playerPoints = 0;
        }
        result.points += playerPoints;
    }
    results.Add(result);
}
```

The code has the following issues:

1. Takes a lot of time processing.
2. Doesn't accumulate the player's points after each engagement.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: What is an engagement?

Comment: an engagement is a round of play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.Count(); x++)
            {
                int pos = list.IndexOf(player.play.pId);
                playerPoints = numPlayers - pos;
            }
```

will assign the variable `playerPoints` each time so after the `for` loop is finished it will have the value of the last item in the `list`

i think you need something like

```
playerPoints = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < list.Count(); x++)
            {
                int pos = list.IndexOf(player.play.pId);
                playerPoints += numPlayers - pos;
            }
```

as for performance

i can see in your code that you are calculating the variable `circuits` for each player but not using any information related to this player .. so you can probably calculate it once before entering the foreach

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Modar Na, your suggestion worked for me. In addition, I had to call `yield return`to return the points.

The code is:

```
foreach (var p in players)
                        {
                        singleCircuitPoints result = new singleCircuitPoints();

                        result.player = p.play;
                        result.team = p.team;
                        result.points = _calculatePoints(p.play, allCircuits).LastOrDefault();
                        results.Add(result);`
```

The _calculatePoints method is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<int> _calculatePoints(Player player, IEnumerable<Registration> circuits)
        {
        int points = 0;
        foreach (Competition c in circuits.Where(c => c.pId == player.pId).Select(r => r.competition))
            {
            if (player.registrations.Any(p => p.compId == c.compId))
                {
                var circuit = from a in circuits where a.compId == c.compId select a;
                int numPlayers = circuit.Count();
                List<int> list = circuit.OrderBy(r => r.score.Sum()).ThenBy(r => r.orderedStroke).Select(r => r.pId).ToList();
                int pos = list.IndexOf(player.pId);
                yield return points += numPlayers - pos;
                }
            else
                {
                yield return points += 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Am left with the challenge of slow performance.`

Comment: Since you are getting the var `circuit` always from `circuits` then ordering .. why not order the `circuits` once before you pass it to the function

Comment: Although passing it to the function will make a copy of it foreach player so if you have large data that would also waste time copying it .. why not make it global variable or static ..